# how to set border radius in donut chart in apex chart

Tags: angular, pie-chart, apexcharts

1. How to set border radius in pie-chart in apex-chart

   this.chartOptions = {
   colors: ["#00978F", "#036CAD",],
   series: [79.9, 20.1,
   ],

   chart: {
   type: "donut",
   height: 300,
   width:260,
   borderRadius:15,
   borderWidth: 15,

   },
   dataLabels: {
   enabled: false,

   },
   plotOptions: {
   pie :{
   expandOnClick: false,
   radius: 30,
   borderRadius: 7,
   donut: {
   radius: 30,
   borderRadius: 7,
   columnWidth: "25%",
   size: '75%',
   labels: {
   borderRadius: 10,
   show: true,
   total: {
   show: true,
   showAlways: true,
   fontSize: '22px',
   fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
   fontWeight: 600,
   label: '',
   formatter: () => 7,

   ```
         },
         solidgauge: {
           borderRadius: 15,
           borderWidth: 5,
         },
         value:{
           offsetY: -8,
           color:'#FF00FF'
         }
       }
     },
   }
   ```

   },
   stroke: {
   radius: 50,
   innerRadius: 50,
   colors: ["#00978F", "#036CAD",],
   borderRadius:15,
   },
   legend: {
   show: true
   },
   tooltip: {
   enabled: false,
   borderRadius: 10,
   },

   }

Comment: can you explain your problem a little bit more which border radius do you want to set?

Comment: have to change piechart inner border radius @Skipperpk

Comment: Do you want to change the radius of the edges of each color in simple terms or do you want the inner radius to more so that the chart be a little thicker?

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), edit your post and correct the formatting and ask a concrete question or at least describe what you want to achieve, otherwise hardly anyone can help you.